# How to initialize this array in a clean way?

Tags: c++

I am trying to initialize this array in C++ :

**C++**

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
int arr[100];
int i = 10;
    while(i){
        cin >> arr[--i];
    }
return 0;
}
```

This initializes the `array` perfectly, but it returns a `negative status`. How can I solve it?

Comment: Negative status? What do you mean by that?

Comment: What do you mean by "it returns a negative status"?

Comment: CodeBlocks shows : `Process terminated with status -1073741510`

Comment: negative status? please explain

Comment: I'm not sure what this status means, but on the last iteration of the while loop the i variable will have value of -1, which can lead to segmentation fault.

Comment: My bad guys, it won't have a value of -1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The status code means the program didn't get to the last line of your main() function (where it should be return 0), but got killed instead. I guess you just stopped it with CTRL+C.

Comment: But is there a better way to initialize this array?

Comment: Yes, there is - look at my answer just below, its "memset" :)

Comment: memset initializes this array with 0 ( "a better way to initialize this array") What you mean is something trivial like arr[--i] = i;

Comment: @duDE if you want it filled with zeros, `int arr[100] = {0};`, and your `memset()` invoke only fills 100 *bytes*, not 100 `int`s.

Comment: @WhozCraig What if I want the array to be filled variably according to the input?